# Why more space on the stack frame is reserved than is needed in x86

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, disassembly

With reference to the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void do_something(int* ptr) {
    cout << "Got address " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr) << endl;
}

void func() {
    int a;
    do_something(&a);
}

int main() {
    func();
}
```

When I disassemble the `func` function the x86 (I am not sure whether it is x86 or x86_64) code is

```
->  0x100001140 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100001141 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100001144 <+4>:  subq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x100001148 <+8>:  leaq   -0x4(%rbp), %rdi
    0x10000114c <+12>: callq  0x100000f90               ; do_something(int*)
    0x100001151 <+17>: addq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x100001155 <+21>: popq   %rbp
    0x100001156 <+22>: retq   
    0x100001157 <+23>: nopw   (%rax,%rax)
```

I understand that the first push statement is pushing the base pointer to the previous function call on the stack, and then the stack pointer value is copied over to the base pointer.  But then why are 16 bytes reserved for the stack?

Does this have to do with alignment somehow?  The variable `a` needs only 4 bytes..

Also what exactly is the `lea` instruction doing in this function call?  is it just getting the address of the integer relative to the base pointer?  Which in this case seems to be 4 bytes off from the base (assuming that the return address is 4 bytes long and is the first thing on the stack)

Other architectures seem to reserve more than 16 bytes and have other things stored on the base of the stack frame..

Comment: Yes you got it right. It's for aligment, and the `lea` is the `&` operator but it has nothing to do with the return address which is in the other direction. It's `-4` because `sizeof(int)` is `4` and locals are below `rbp` (and also because the compiler decided to assign it in the last 4 bytes from the 16 that it allocated). Note that the return address is in fact 8 bytes in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @Jester I am having a really hard time figuring out what exactly the lea instruction is doing, and I don't want to guess because I feel like that is going to backfire later on.  Could you explain how the argument is passed and what the stack has in this function call?

Comment: Argument is passed in `rdi`, which is why `leaq -0x4(%rbp), %rdi` is used. From `rbp` up you have the pushed `rbp` then the return address to `main`. From `rbp` down you have the local variable `a` followed by 12 unused bytes. The return address to `func` will be placed under that.

Comment: @Jester If this had to do with alignment then why were 16 bytes reserved?  Would 8 bytes not be okay?

Comment: 16 byte alignment is required by the ABI (to make it easier for SSE aligned instructions).

Comment: `Rxx` are 64-bit registers in x86_64, `Exx` are 32-bit "extended" registers in x86

Answer (score 4):

This is x64 code, note the usage of the rsp register.  x86 code uses the esp register.  Most important implementation detail of the x64 ABI is that the stack must always be aligned to 16.  Not actually necessary to properly run 64-bit code, but the alignment guarantee ensures that the compiler can safely emit SSE instructions.  Their operands require 16 byte alignment to be fast.  None are actually used in this snippet but they might be in `do_something`.

Upon entry of your function, the caller's CALL instruction has pushed 8 bytes on the stack to store the return address.  The first PUSH instruction aligns the stack to 16 again, no additional corrections required.

It then creates the stack frame to store the `a` variable.  While only 4 bytes are required, adjusting rsp by only 4 isn't good enough to provide the necessary alignment.  So it picks the next suitable value, 16.  The extra 12 bytes are simply unused.

The LEA instruction is a very handy one that implements `&a`.  LEA = Load Effective Address = "take the address of".  Not a particularly involved calculation here, it gets more convoluted when you use something like `&array[ix]`.  Something that still can be done by a single LEA if the array element size is 1, 2 or 4 bytes long, pretty common.

The -4 is the offset from the start of the stack frame for the `a` variable.  4 bytes are needed to store `int`, your compiler implements the [LP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).  Keep in mind that the stack grows downwards so it isn't 0.

Then it is just making the function call, the rdi register is used to pass the 1st argument in the x64 ABI.  Then it destroys the stack frame again by re-adjusting rsp and restores rbp.

Do keep in mind that you are looking at unoptimized code.  Usually none of this is left after the optimizer is done with it, small functions like this almost always get inlined.  So this doesn't teach you that much practical knowledge of the code that actually runs.  Have a look-see at the -O2 code.

Comment: It's pretty common to use "x86" as a catch-all term that includes long mode as well as 32-bit compat/legacy mode, and 16-bit real mode.  That's not what the OP is doing, but it seems weird to me to say "x86 uses ESP", esp in a non-Windows / MSVC question.  The OP is using AT&T syntax and the x86-64 System V ABI (first arg in RSI).  gcc / Linux often use i386 vs. amd64 (or x86-64) to distinguish 32-bit vs. 64-bit x86.  x64 is almost exclusively used in Windows / Microsoft terminology.

Comment: Anyway, the i386 System V ABI has also required 16B stack alignment for years now, so this is not specific to x86-64.  (ABI links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)

Comment: It is strong illusion at SO that 16-bit code is still relevant.  Created by students that have trouble finishing their homework assignment.  I'm not that keen in doing *anything* to promote that illusion.

Comment: @PeterCordes 16 bit code is fun! Currently working on my 80286 protected mode operating system.

Answer (score 0):

According to x86-64 ABI, the stack must be 16 byte aligned prior to a subroutine call.

```
leaq (mem), reg
```

is equivalent to the following

```
reg = &(*mem) = mem
```